# sendSubviewToBack question:where to send

Tags: iphone

I have a UIView and there are 5 subViews on it with index

0,1,2,3,4,5

I hope to know

for the subview with index 5: subView5

the code

```
[self.subView5 sendSubviewToBack]
```

send the subview to 4 or 0?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendSubViewToBack will send your view to index 0